# Вопрос по пространствам имен Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

есть

```
# define QT_USE_NAMESPACE
# define QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
# define QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

в заголовках встречается что то вроде

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QVBoxLayout;
QT_END_NAMESPACE
```

в чем глубинный смысл этих дефайнов?

Это же не макросы. Зачем они нужны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации объясняется](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_In_Namespace). Кратко - при определенных конфигурациях на линуксе можно получить багу - креш приложения. Что бы пофиксить, придумали завернуть код в namespace. Но так как эта бага проявляется только в определенных специфических условиях, то оно обычно не нужно.

Поэтому, в большинстве случаев эти define разворачиваются в пустую строку. Но можно при сборке Qt указать специальный флажок `-qtnamespace xxx` и тогда там будет нужный namespace. И все это накладывает на разработчиков требования правильно оформлять свой код.

Comment: т.е. код 
 `   
     QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
     class QVBoxLayout;
     QT_END_NAMESPACE
`
оборачивается нэймспасом только если указать ключик при сборке?

Comment: да. При сборке своего Qt. А так - это просто пустота.

Comment: понятно. Спасибо!